# Can a Dedicated Server Configuration for LAMP Hosting be Done "in the Cloud"?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, lamp, cloud

Right now, one of our product offerings is basically LAMP web hosting. We host a PHP CMS, lots of images, and sometimes WordPress in each Apache host–all across multiple linux dedicated boxes. Our clients also have FTP access to their host. Each Apache host has 1 or more mysql databases.

My question is: **can this setup be done using some combination of stock cloud services (from AWS or Rackspace)?**. If I can avoid having to spin up new dedicated boxes every month or two or save money, that'd be great.

EC2 and RS Cloud Servers have no or little local storage. I could update my CMS to upload files to S3 but I still lose FTP and possibly WordPress. It seems block storage may be the answer. I'm just not sure how all the pieces fit together, specifically with storage and DBs.

Comment: Why not set up a private cloud yourself? You seem to have enough hardware to go around.

Comment: I suppose you could do it, but I doubt you would save money. I expect it would be a lot more expensive to use someone else's public cloud than to maintain your own.

Comment: @fuero so, you're saying tie my dedicated boxes together and virtualize them? What do I gain?

Comment: Among other things, the ability to migrate running services from failing hardware without downtime.

Comment: so you want to use cloud hosting according to your question, you want to pay someone to do it for you. Encountering the suggestion that it's cheaper to do it yourself, you ask what gains you get from cloud hosting in general?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve all ur requirement in amazon cloud go with m1.large instance u will get 800 Gb of space after doing RAID0 I belive that will be enough.

1. Apache - yes
2. FTP    - yes
3. Mysql  - yes

Comment: How exactly do you get 800GB of storage? Through EBS?

Comment: You can attach EBS to your EC2 Instance .But EBS is very low in i/o instead of that you should do RAID 0 on your EC2 .